# SQL 2008 SP1 XML Value from ntext Column

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a column that contains the following xml:

```
<obj xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="urn:vim25" versionId="5.1" xsi:type="ArrayOfKeyAnyValue">
  <KeyAnyValue xsi:type="KeyAnyValue">
    <key>1</key>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">naa.6019cbc1a09e175d370df5320b00803a</value>
  </KeyAnyValue>
  <KeyAnyValue xsi:type="KeyAnyValue">
    <key>2</key>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">6215</value>
  </KeyAnyValue>
  <KeyAnyValue xsi:type="KeyAnyValue">
    <key>3</key>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1291898</value>
  </KeyAnyValue>
</obj>
```

I wish to return each of the key values as a separate column. I have tried:

```
SELECT [table].[column1]
  ,CONVERT(xml, [table].[column1]).value('(/obj/KeyAnyValue[1]/value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)') As KeyValue
from [table]
```

This just returns NULL. Have I got the XML path right?

Sure something simple I am doing wrong and much appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your XPath expression has to say what namespace it's working with:

```
declare @data xml = '<obj xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
                          xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
                          xmlns="urn:vim25" versionId="5.1" 
                          xsi:type="ArrayOfKeyAnyValue">
  <KeyAnyValue xsi:type="KeyAnyValue">
    <key>1</key>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">naa.6019cbc1a09e175d370df5320b00803a</value>
  </KeyAnyValue>
  <KeyAnyValue xsi:type="KeyAnyValue">
    <key>2</key>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">6215</value>
  </KeyAnyValue>
  <KeyAnyValue xsi:type="KeyAnyValue">
    <key>3</key>
    <value xsi:type="xsd:string">1291898</value>
  </KeyAnyValue>
</obj>'

select @data.value('declare namespace a="urn:vim25";
(/a:obj/a:KeyAnyValue[1]/a:value)[1]', 'nvarchar(max)')
```

Produces:

```
naa.6019cbc1a09e175d370df5320b00803a
```